# Laravel Validator fails when try to upload img file

Tags: laravel-4

If i want to upload a img it fails. *.png files are ok.
Image sizes are acceptable.
Without validator, *.png are uploaded without any problem.

```
$validator = Validator::make([
        'image'     =>      Input::file('img')

    ], [
        'image'     =>      'mimes:png, jpg, jpeg | max:5120'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return 'Error is occured while uploading file.';
    }
```

Comment: You mean `*.png` don't you?

Comment: Yes sorry i mean *.png files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces & it should work.

Rename this:

`'mimes:png, jpg, jpeg | max:5120'`

To this:

`'mimes:png,jpg,jpeg|max:5120'`